# X server on 15.10 keeps crushing and restarting at login

Tags: xorg

My X window keeps crushing and loading to the login screen especially when am watching a video and I decide to skip forward. I am wondering what I did wrong

Comment: Just a stab here, what GPU are you using and were you using the old fglrx AMD drivers if using AMD before upgrading?

Comment: can you post the  the output of `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: @Neil this is the out put [link](http://pastebin.com/Fpe2tB7J)

Comment: @cossacksman **00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0c)**

Comment: Probably not the issue here but are you running Docky? A lot of the early lines look familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Cairo.Surface leaks are all over your logs as well as some other Docky failures covering the top-most parts of your logs, it sounds irrational but try running without it. If you're not running Docky then it may be that something else is looking for Cairo.Surface and other libraries/icons but it's a good place to start. If it's crashing upon login and you're logging in from an X interface then it has to be something loaded after the user, of course.

Comment: I am not running cairo... but I have a docky instance running. I think I will disable it to see what will happen. I will keep you posted

Comment: How did it go? I only did a quick skim of the syslog because of it's size but I can take a closer look if that isn't the issue.

Comment: I have re-installed ubuntu and the problem still persists. xwindow crushes after i skip the movie a couple of times and I have to wait a couple of seconds before I can login again